# Using WebViewActivity.EXTRA_URL in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, twitter4j

The development goal is to use twitter4j to communicate between the android app and twitter servers. At this specific point, initially the Twitter callback URL is displayed and then with the use of `Intent`  the information is placed and then sent to the next activity (`WebViewActivity`).
I need to use the code below in kotlin.
The android studio does the conversion, but not completely correct. Error appear on the third lines of code ("Unresolved reference: EXTRA_URL").

in java

```
requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(callbackUrl);   
final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,WebViewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(WebViewActivity.EXTRA_URL, requestToken.getAuthenticationURL());
startActivityForResult(intent, WEBVIEW_REQUEST_CODE);
```

conversion to kotlin from android studio

```
requestToken = twitter?.getOAuthRequestToken(callbackUrl)
val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, WebViewActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra(WebViewActivity.EXTRA_URL, requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())
startActivityForResult(intent,WEBVIEW_REQUEST_CODE)
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: "Unresolved reference: EXTRA_URL"